# Hasura Cloud Run and Cloud SQL pool settings/database errors

Tags: postgresql, docker, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, hasura

We're using Cloud Run and Cloud SQL on our current setup with Hasura `2.0.9` (GCP)

Cloud Run is setup to run minimum 5 instances and max 150 and about ~80-90 instances are running on average.

Cloud SQL is setup to accept up to 500 connections (4vCPU and 15GB of RAM)

Average requests per second on Cloud Run are ~350

I'm getting errors on Cloud SQL:

`db=postgres,user=postgres FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections`

and:

`db=postgres,user=postgres FATAL: sorry, too many clients already`

And  500/503 errors on Cloud Run:

```
severity: "ERROR". <--- 500
textPayload: "The request failed because the instance could not start successfully."
```

```
severity: "ERROR" <--- 503
textPayload: "The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error."
```

This is the `databases.yaml`

```
- name: default
  kind: postgres
  configuration:
    connection_info:
      database_url:
        from_env: HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL
      isolation_level: read-committed
      pool_settings:
        connection_lifetime: 600
        idle_timeout: 180
        max_connections: 400
        retries: 1
      use_prepared_statements: true
  tables: "!include default/tables/tables.yaml"
  functions: "!include default/functions/functions.yaml"
```

Is the above yaml ok to use or I should limit the `max_connections` down to 150 instances / 500 (db connection limit)  = ~2 `max_connections`? Right now on the database monitoring I see that the connections are getting beyond the `400` `max_connections` setting of the pool and hit the `500` connections limit of Cloud SQL.

I cannot find a sweet spot so the infrastructure won't fail. I even tried to use `pgpool` (I've removed `pool_settings` from `databases.yaml`) but it won't get better. I've been trying combinations for the last couple days with no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Create a network topology diagram. Add the max connections limitations on all items. You can update with this your question. My suggestions are, either reduce Cloud Run instances, and increase concurrency on existing instances. Less separate connections, but more traffic on one connection.  And/or definitely increase the max_connections to something large, until you don't hit some other limits, like memory, or TCP limits.

Comment: @Pentium10 thanks for your comment. Cloud Run limits each instance connection to SQL to 100 connections as per Cloud SQL quotas and limits. I have no clue how Hasura is handling horizontal scale with connection pool setting, eg. Every single instance has a pool of 400 connections (by using `databases.yaml` above) or does this pool "spreads" across instances? I can set a flag on Cloud SQL to increase `max_connections`, I'll try to implement your thoughts and come back.

Comment: How did you connected Cloud Run with Cloud SQL? If you just use the connector then there are limits in place, but if you create a VPC connector, there are totally different limits, and it might be a good scalability upgrade. Are you using VPC with Cloud Run and Cloud SQL? If not try that out.

Comment: @Pentium10 No VPC connector, I ll try this out. I’ve already increased the `max_connections` flag on database to 4.000 conmections, increased the Cloud Run instance max clients to 596 and 0 errors so far for the last 7hrs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ran into Cloud Run -> Cloud SQL connection limits which is 100 connections according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas#cloud-run-limits) quota page.

A good upgrade would be to **swap connector based database connections, with a VPC Network based approach.**

There is an extensive guide put together by @guilaume about VPC Connectors with Cloud Run.

[Cloud SQL with private IP only: the Good, the Bad and the Ugly](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-sql-with-private-ip-only-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-de4ac23ce98a)

Comment: I've also had to reduce the `max_connections` of Hasura's `pool_settings`, it seems 400 is an overkill and it was causing performance issues. I've reduced them to `24` (didn't used default of `50`) and everything seems stable so far. Just a side note in case someone misses this, if you enable Private IP on Cloud SQL there is no turning back and you'll have to use VPN to connect to the database from your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is pretty good, but in case someone finds this question and need a quick alternative, before moving into the vpc

- **You could add the max_connections flag and increase the default value on the Cloud SQL.**

> Cloud SQL is setup to accept up to 500 connections (4vCPU and 15GB of RAM)

500 is the default value.

| Size | Default max connections |
| --- | --- |
| tiny (~0.5) | 25 |
| small (~1.7) | 50 |
| from 3.75 to < 6 | 100 |
| from 6 to < 7.5 | 200 |
| from 7.5 to < 15 | 400 |
| from 15 to < 30 | 500 |
| from 30 to < 60 | 600 |
| from 60 to < 120 | 800 |
| >=120 | 1,000 |

The [Google cloud sql docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#config) has the above table, and instructions to add the flag.